# Move files/table following selection criteria

Tags: bash, mv, table

Considering a variable `a` describing temperature series for the city `a`. I have 9 directories (`a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, `a5`, `a6`, `a7`, `a8`, `a9`) each of them containing a table (respectively `a1.txt`, `a2.txt`, `a3.txt`, `a4.txt`, `a5.txt`, `a6.txt`, `a7.txt`, `a8.txt`, `a9.txt`).

I would like to move to another directory the table presenting the highest value at the first row and fourth column (with space separator). Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supposed to be a "write this program for me" site, so I am assuming that you have no idea where to start. So here's one way:

```
#!/bin/bash
highest=-999
for x in a[0-9]/a[0-9].txt;do
    fourth="$(awk 'NR==1{print $4}' $x)"
    if [ $highest -lt $fourth ];then
        highest=$fourth
        hifile=$x
    fi
done
echo "highest was $highest in $hifile"
mv $hifile high/
```

A brief of what the above code does: 
loops through all directory/file combinations named `a[0-9]/a[0-9].txt`
it uses awk to assign the fourth field (`{print $4}`) from the first line (`NR==1`) to the variable fourth. It then compares if highest is less than fourth (`if [ $highest -lt $fourth ];then`), and if so saves the filename in the hifile variable. When the loop is done, it moves the file to the directory "high"

Comment: If none of the fourth-field values are higher than -999, you could end up with an undefined $hifile; consider priming $highest & $hifile with one of the input values. I'll have to remember the `awk NR==1` part, though - thanks!

Comment: @jeff-schaller He said they would be temperatures, so -999 felt pretty safe. But point taken.

Comment: @Mel Thank you this solution seems to work, but I have an issue with the line ´if [ $highest -lt $fourth ];then´ giving the error message "integer expression expected". Do you have an idea to workaround this around?

Comment: @steve sounds like you didn't set the initial value at the top `highest=-999`. You can either do that, or quote the values like: `if [ "$highest" -lt "$fourth" ];then`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used to generate the files you're talking about:

```
mkdir -p       another/directory
for   n in     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do    mkdir   -p "a$n"
      printf  "$n $n $n 1$n $n $n $n $n\n" >"a$n/a$n.txt"   #1 marks 4th col
done
```

This is what I used to `mv` the file:

```
 mv "a$(((a=$(t=$(printf \\t)
 paste a[1-9]/a[1-9].txt /dev/null |
 sed -e"s/\( *[^ ][^ ]*[ $t]\)\{4\}[^$t]*/\1/g;y| |\n|;q" |
 sort -rn | head -n1))-10))/a${a#1}.txt" another/directory
```

And this is what I did to verify I'd got it right:

```
cat another/directory/*
```

---

```
9 9 9 19 9 9 9 9
```

...but I didn't get it right. That depends on the highest value matching the file's name. This doesn't:

```
file=$(
    grep -n . ./a[1-9]/a[1-9].txt |
    grep :1: |     cut -d\  -f1,4 |
    sort -rnk2,2
)
mv "${file%%:*}" another/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do it, of course, but here's one way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# start out assuming 1 is the highest
highfile=a1/a1.txt
highval=$(head -1 a1/a1.txt | awk '{print $4}')
for a in `seq 2 9`
do
  val=$(head -1 a$a/a$a.txt | awk '{print $4}')
  if [ $val -gt $highval ]
  then
    highfile=a$a/a$a.txt
    highval=$val
  fi
done

echo mv $highfile destdir
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a breeze with `gawk`

```
awk -v target_dir="$TARGET_DIR" '
  {a[FILENAME] = $4; nextfile}; 
  END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc";
  for(k in a){system("mv "k" "target_dir); exit}}' */*.txt
```